# In Blazor WebAssembly, how to write a warning or an info?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

In Blazor WebAssembly, `Console.WriteLine` writes a log to the Javascript console, and `Console.Error.WriteLine` writes an error.  Is there any way to write a warning or an info without using Javascript--what is the Blazor equivalent of Javascript `console.warn` or `console.info`?

(In general, how can one find out if there is a Blazor alternative to Javascript interop for any given function call?)

Comment: Not clear what you want? Console.WriteLine is C# code. It goes to the Browser console. If you want a different logging system there are several; eg Serilog to name one

Comment: I have added a clarifying sentence.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible but I've yet to experiment with it in webassembly. Here's something that I came across that may be promising. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-logging-framework-in-blazor-with-net-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way of doing this in Blazor without Javascript interop, as of 3.2.0-preview4.

Answer (score 6):

#### UPDATE for preview5

The default logger use log level to write in the console now you don't need to create your logger.

```cs
@using using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject ILogger<MyComponent> _logger
...
@code {

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {
          _logger.LogWarning("warning");
          _logger.LogError("error");
     }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b69457e606adf24f9bb76014bba3eea65c51b954/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly/src/Services/WebAssemblyConsoleLogger.cs

#### Before preview 5

You can use JSInterop:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime
...
@code {

     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
          await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.error", "ERROR").ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
}
```

Or implement your logger :

```cs
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    public ConsoleLogger(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsRuntime));
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return NoOpDisposable.Instance;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return logLevel >= LogLevel.Warning;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        var formattedMessage = formatter(state, exception);
        switch(logLevel)
        {
            case LogLevel.Critical:
            case LogLevel.Error:
                _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.error", formattedMessage);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Warning:
                _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.warn", formattedMessage);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Information:
                _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.info", formattedMessage);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Trace:
            case LogLevel.Debug:
                _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.debug", formattedMessage);
                break;
            default:
                _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", formattedMessage);
                break;
        }
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Major Code Smell", "S3881:\"IDisposable\" should be implemented correctly", Justification = "From default console logger")]
    [SuppressMessage("Critical Code Smell", "S2223:Non-constant static fields should not be visible", Justification = "From default console logger")]
    [SuppressMessage("Critical Code Smell", "S1186:Methods should not be empty", Justification = "From default console logger")]
    private class NoOpDisposable : IDisposable
    {            
        public static NoOpDisposable Instance = new NoOpDisposable();
            
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

Your logger provider

```cs
public class ConsoleLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _services;
    ILogger _logger;
    public ConsoleLoggerProvider(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _services = services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        if (_logger != null)
        {
            return _logger;
        }

        using var provider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var jsRuntime = provider.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
        _logger = new ConsoleLogger(jsRuntime);
        return _logger;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // nothing to dispose.
    }
}
```

Inject it in DI:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);            
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
    builder.Services.AddLogging(options =>
    {
        options.ClearProviders();
        options.AddProvider(new ConsoleLoggerProvider(options.Services));
    });
```

An inject an `ILogger<T>` in your components or services and use this logger to log in the console with warning or error level

```cs
@using using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject ILogger<MyComponent> _logger
...
@code {

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {
          _logger.LogWarning("warning");
          _logger.LogError("error");
     }
}
```

Comment: This does not produce actual console warning or error messages. When I call Javascript `console.warn("test");` in Chrome's console, I get "test" on a pale yellow background with a warning icon.  Your solution just gives me a plain message with `[Error]` or `[Warning]` in front of it, which isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Which version do you use ?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I updated the response with a full code implementing a logger

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to do this without using Javascript.  Perhaps there is no way.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski nope, no other way to use the browser console

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski There's some improvement in blazor loggin in preview4: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-4-release-now-available/

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski since preview 5, the default logger use log level to write in the console